# No release bundle folder after upgrading Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar

> I recently upgraded my Android Studio to version 2.3 with the corresponding gradle version.

**I have two modules inside my project, which i exported as a jar using gradle functions like this:**

```
task createJar(type: Copy) {
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
into('libs/')
include('classes.jar')
rename('classes.jar', 'myExample.jar')
}
createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

> - However after the upgrade, this does not work anymore. In Android Studio i set the Build Variant to "Release", but after running my tasks there will be no JAR in my lib folder. I checked the `build/intermediates/bundles/` folder and theres no release folder generated. There will be just a `default` and a `debug` folder.
> - Any way to get an external JAR from a release build again?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the proper solution but I added this to my gradle file within the android section and the release folder has returned.

```
publishNonDefault true
```

Comment: I simply had no folder called 'build/intermediates/bundles/release/' and the exportJar() function wasn't working. This solution also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Android studio 3.1+ the build path got changed. So change the path to "**build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/**".

```
task exportJar(type: Copy)
{
    from('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'NAME.jar')
}
```

Comment: No such folder on on Android Studio 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in 2023 year is replace path `''build/intermediates/bundles/release/''` with `'build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/release/'`