# Android studio unable to find bundle folder while generating .jar file

Tags: android-studio, jar, bundle

I have used android studio, developed android project and then i just make my android project as .jar file by using the following code in build.gradle, but unable to find the bundle folder inside the intermediates

```
task deleteJar(type: Delete){
   delete 'libs/logmanagmentlib.jar'
}

task createJar(type: Copy){
   from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
   into('libs/')
   include('classes.jar')
   rename('classes.jar','logmanagmentlib.jar')
}

createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar,build)
```

[My refrence document](http:////www.quora.com/in/How-do-I-build-jar-file-in-Android-studio-using-gradle) i have reffered this document for generating jar file

[image]

Comment: have the same problem. did you found the solution?

Comment: This post might address your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039532/no-release-bundle-folder-after-upgrading-android-studio